# Mask array of different sizes, then replace elements from another one

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, list-comprehension, mask

I have two arrays of different size `a` and `b`, and I want to obtain a new array with the same size as the largest one (`a_and_b`), and with elements that have `zeros` everywhere except when the difference between any of the two elements is minimum. Then I want to replace its non-zero elements with the elements of another array of the same size as the first one

```
a = np.asarray([1, 3])
b = np.asarray([0.8, 0.95, 1.1, 1.25, 1.40, 1.55, 1.70, 1.85, 2.00, 2.15, 2.30, 2.45, 2.60, 2.75, 2.90, 3.05])
c = np.asarray([15.145, 18.191])

a_and_b = [0 0.95 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3.05]
final = [0 15.145 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 18.191]
```

How do I obtain the `final`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be [0 0.95 0 0 ... 0 3.05]?

Comment: True. edited. thanks

Comment: Could you clarify `except when the difference is minimum` ? All adjacent items of `b` have the same difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([1, 3])
b = np.asarray([0.8, 0.95, 1.1, 1.25, 1.40, 1.55, 1.70, 1.85, 2.00, 2.15, 2.30, 2.45, 2.60, 2.75, 2.90, 3.05])
c = np.asarray([15.145, 18.191])

a_and_b, final = np.zeros_like(b), np.zeros_like(b)
min_ba = (abs(b.reshape(1,-1)-a.reshape(-1,1)).argmin(axis=1))
a_and_b[min_ba] = b[min_ba]
final[min_ba] = c
print(a_and_b)
print(final)
```

Out:

```
[0.   0.95 0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.
 0.   3.05]
[ 0.    15.145  0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
  0.     0.     0.     0.     0.    18.191]
```

Comment: Very good. I am going to accept you answer, but first I was wondering if there is a more pythonic way to do so? I was sure I have had used list comprehension to do that (but maybe I am just wrong)

Comment: Yeah you can use list comprehensions, but they're slow as they're basically for loops. In the code above, I take advantage of numpy's broadcasting to completely skip any loops or list comprehension. Let's say you have 10 elements in a and 20 elements in b. Then you would find the minimum indexes in b for a elements by the list comprehension: [abs(b-val).argmin() for val in a]. But in my code, I'm reshaping b to size (1,20) and a as (10,1), so subtracting b-a automatically gives me an array of size (10,20), after which we take argmin along columns.

Comment: The remaining part is simple assignment; we don't need any loops or comprehensions here to calculate a_and_b or final.